# How to localize tableView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, localization

I'm translating my app to multiple languages, storyboard translations are working perfectly, but I'm struggling to localize the content of tableView (tableView cell) and corresponding viewController.

I have created string file Localizable.strings for 2 languages so far.

FirstViewController contains an array with names which is passed to TableViewCell as UILabel and later to corresponding DetailViewController.

TableViewCell:

```
class UpperTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var upperImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var upperBodyType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var upperLblName: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

The objectID reference in Main.strings of the name label is 
"BkN-Wi-Ai3.text" = "Label1";

However I can't figure out how to translate and parse the translated data of the name array and bodyType array into labels in TableView.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following steps:

Make String extension (Tablename should be your .strings file):

```
extension String {
 
    func localized(bundle: Bundle = .main, tableName: String = "Localized”) -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: tableName, value: "**\(self)**", comment: "")
    }
}
```

After that update your **awakeFromNib**:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
upperBodyType.text = upperBodyType.text?.localized()
upperLblName.text = upperLblName.text?.localized()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Razib, I have to add, in order to fully translate the data/value/text of array in your TableView, Cells, you have to add .localized() to every value, e.g. arrayOne = ["text1".localized(), "text2".localized, and so on..